# How to read raw variable through socket with custom datatype in C?

Tags: c, sockets, variables

I am working on a `client-socket` project to send a custom datatype (myMail) from client to the server through Linux `socket` programming. Here is my client code:

```c
struct mail pmail;
connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa));
send(clientSocket, &pmail, sizeof(pmail), 0);
```

And for my server, which is the problematic part:

```c
int new_socket = .....;
char buffer[1024] = { 0 };
valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 1024 - 1);
strut mail pmail;
pmail = &buffer;
```

The problem is that after compilation, it says `operand types are ‘mail’ and ‘char (*)[1024]’`. So, I wonder if there is any method to allow me to assign variable pmail's content to buffer? Or I have to try an alternative way?

Comment: While the problem you ask about is easy to solve (just cast `&pmail`, e.g. `(char *) &pmail`), there is likely other problems with this approach. What *is* the `mail` type? Is it a structure? Does it contain pointers? Are both the sender and receiver using the same *endianness*?

Comment: Also note that if you're using TCP, then it's a stream-oriented protocol without "messages", "packets" or boundaries. You need to tell the receiving site either what it's about to receive, or send a header that includes the size, or introduce your own message boundaries. And on the receiving side you need to use loops, because one call to `read` might return less than a single message. Or more (for example multiple messages, of which the last might be partial).

Comment: You can read directlyinto your variable: `read(new_socket, &pmail, sizeof pmail);` or copy from buffer ´memcpy(´&pmail, buffer, sizeof pmail);` But that still requires that the variable has identical layout on both machines and doesn't contain pointers as mentioned by Some programmer dude

Comment: Excuse the first part of my first comment, the problem isn't what I though it was... It's the assignment `pmail=&buffer;` which is wrong in multiple ways. First of all, you should not use the pointer-to operator `&`. Secondly you can't assign from an array of bytes to a structure. Either read directly into the structure, or use `memcpy` to copy the data. Both those solutions are mentioned by @Gerhardh. Now, should you really do that? See the rest of my first comment. It might simply not be possible.

Comment: I recommend you do some research about *serialization*. Serialize the structure into a text-based format (like for example JSON) and send it as plain text. Then on the receiving end, deserialize it. There are libraries available that can do both, for custom formats or for common ones like JSON or XML.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your response, however I wonder why it's impossible to send the variable directly? Can't it be readable for both server and client as long as they have the same datatype definition? BTW, the type ``mail`` is a class that have a string and int variable in public access specifiers. If it's required to do serialization, is it better to use JSON or create a custom protocol (like SMTP but simpler)?

Comment: If the structure contains pointers, those are local to the process and can't be passed to other processes, not even ones running the same program on the same computer. If all you have is an *array* of characters (not a pointer) and a plain `int` value, then you can pass it using sockets. But again, if the sender and receiver are using different *endianness* then the `int` value will need to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

Cast `buffer` to a pointer of your `struct mail`:

```
int new_socket = .....;
char buffer[1024] = { 0 };
valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 1024 - 1);
if (valread)
    struct mail* pmail = (struct mail*)buffer;
```

Or simply:

```
int new_socket = .....;
struct mail pmail;
valread = read(new_socket, &pmail, sizeof(struct mail));
```

Comment: That is dangerous: `(struct mail*)buffer;` This would require that `buffer` is located on an address that meets alignment requirements for type `struct mail`. With type `char[]` there are no alignment requirements for `buffer` and accessing it via such a cast may cause undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <errno.h> /* for errno */
#include <stdio.h> /* for fprintf, etc */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, etc. */
#include <string.h> /* for strerror(), etc. */
.......
int new_socket = .....;
strut mail pmail;
valread = read(new_socket, &pmail, sizeof pmail);
if (valread < 0) { /* ERROR */
    fprintf(stderr,
           "read: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (valread < sizeof pmail) { 
    /* incomplete read, this can happen if the socket needs to
     * send the whole structure in several parts, but as you don't
     * follow any rule to handle a fractional data received and read,
     * the possible differences in binary representation at client or
     * server side, we can only pray to have everything ok, if we
     * reach here, the only thing we can do is to signal an error. */
    fprintf(stderr,
          "read: expected %d but received only %d bytes, cannot continue\n",
          sizeof pmail, valread);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
/* if you got here, pray for the structures to be represented the same way
 * in both machines, and you can continue. */
```